# Change AppBar Icons Color in Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, application-bar

I am using ApplicationBar Icons with size 48x48 PNG files,with transparent background.
But I colored Icons as per my App theme i.e. orange, but when i tried the icon in my app it is showing me the foreground color of icon as **white** not orange.

**How can we use `ApplicationBar` Icons with foreground color other than white ?**

Thanks.

Comment: I am also facing this problem, and need three different colored buttons in the app bar. So, how can I implement this? please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use white icons and set the ForegroundColor property of the application bar to Orange. The icons will show in orange:

```xaml
<shell:ApplicationBar ForegroundColor="Orange">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change it both from XAML & CS.Here I change foreground & background with opacity of applicationBar.

XAML

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
   <shell:ApplicationBar BackgroundColor="Black" 
                         ForegroundColor="Red"
                         IsVisible = true;
                         Opacity="0.9" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

CS

```
ApplicationBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.Black;
ApplicationBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.Red;
ApplicationBar.Opacity = 0.9;
ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
```